# Awarding a bounty to an undeserving answer

Tags: discussion, bounty

I put out a bounty on a question I made in order to call attention to it. While this had the intended effect and my post received an answer, said answer was incorrect. I got notified that I must award the bounty to an answer within 24 hours. I do not think this should be done, as it would give the impression that I am satisfied with the results, which I am not. I would rather increase the bounty than give it to an undeserving answer. What is done in these cases?

Comment: The short version is that you are not required to award the bounty.  If the grace period expires, the answer with the highest net score over 2 will receive half of the bounty (unless you have accepted that answer).  You cannot modify a bounty once you have issued it.  If you are unsatisfied with the result of your bounty, you can always try offering another bounty.

Comment: You can always leave a comment on the "undeserving answer", explaining exactly howe it falls short of your hopes & expectations.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I did, and while the answerer tried to improve their post, their solution was still incorrect.

Comment: @GuachoPerez I took a look at your post, and while the bounty has expired I retain an interest. You may refresh th bounty if you wish, but I'll try to find time to work on your question.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon if you provide a correct solution I will refresh the bounty so I may award you the amount in full if you wish.

Comment: @GuachoPerez Aha! I am not very optimistic about giving a perfect answer, but I'll try to help you for sure. It may take time : all my contributions do!